# nice way to display data row by row

Tags: html, css, design

I often see many tutorials about how to make forms pretty, but I don't see as many showing how you can display the result in a pretty way. I mean, when the data has been input and you'd like to display it, but you don't want the data to seem editable, so you don't want to show the values in input fields and drop downs. You don't want to display it in a datatable or the likes either, because you only want one row from the db.

You just wntn to display the form row by row, but without the form elements, and without it looking boring because it's "just text". Does anyone have a good css guide og html guide or something third on how to structure the display of such data so it looks good?

I'm asking Because I want to display some form-data in fancybox, but all the fancybox really does right now is build you up to let you down, because the box looks good, but then it's just filled with plane looking, badly spaced text.

**EDIT**
Should've brought an example - so My form looks like:

> ```
> Field1 : Input
> Field2 : Input
> Field3 : Input
> ```

and so forth and I want to display the same, but without the form fields

> ```
> Field1 : Input
> Field2 : Input
> Field3 : Input
> ```

but In my opinion it just looks weak. Form fields look nice, but plane text just doesn't look that eye-appealing. Maybe it's just my styling, so that's why I'm asking, what are good conventions for spacing and such. Have anybody seen someone get creative with this form of presentation? It's pretty simple, and it should be, nothing too fancy, but nothing too 90's either.

Comment: Are you looking for a design better design or some kind of remark on whether you should use some kind of tabular markup or table-less markup? Have you looked into any CSS Frameworks?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want this to look like?

Comment: @Wex - I'm not familiar with that - do you have any good one's so I can get a feel of what it's like?

Comment: @Ek0nomik - I updated the question, sorry I didn't supply this information the first time. I hope you catch my drift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to make a summary like page for a user, you can use the `disabled="disabled"` attribute to show the data entered in formfields but since they are disabled (and thus greyed out) do not seem editable.

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_disabled) from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

Another idea I found broadly accepted is to design the data output in the exact same way it is ment to be used later on. For Example if it would be used for an invoice you can preview the invoice with a nice letter head representing the input values.

Comment: I liked the idea about displaying the data in the way it's ment to be used - that's a really good way of looking at it. Thank you for your answer.